# DVWP lookup dropdowns in edit view?

Tags: data-view-web-part

I'm using the DVWP to view and edit a few SQL Server database tables.

Is it possible to use a dropdown control to display values in an edit form?  Let's say I'm editing a row in a table called Fruits, and there is a field called "Type" which is a foreign key reference to a table called FruitTypes.  I would like to select the fruit "type" from a dropdown list bound to the FruitTypes table.

It's a pretty straightforward question, though I seem to be having a difficult time asking it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "yes", at least fro a DVWP perspective. Check out my blog post on this:
http://sympmarc.com/2008/01/03/firing-an-event-when-a-user-selects-a-value-from-a-data-view-web-part-dropdown/

Comment: I'm not sure that's what I'm after.  I want only one of my columns to be a dropdown with values from a reference table.  So instead of FruitType being "0" or "1" or "2" (the key), I want it to be "Apple" or "Orange", etc. (the value corresponding to the key in the referenced table).